# When start a container with avahi-daemon and avahi-brower, avahi-browser not working in container

Tags: docker, containers, dbus, avahi

I used the exact files and installation steps for this [docker image](https://github.com/ianblenke/docker-avahi). The container is running in my Ubuntu system, but I couldn't get avahi-browse to work inside the container. I tested dbus-send to rule out d-bus issue, and dbus-send works.
This is the error I got,

root@1235c937454f:/# avahi-browse -at

Failed to create client object: Daemon not running

Could anyone help?

tried db-send and it worked.